# How to fix materialize modal issue

Tags: html, jquery, css, materialize

[image]I am using materialize.css for our project I used materialize popup. My simple requirement is popup should be a vertical center of the body. Yes I tried my self it's also working well but some issue facing with that. Inside popup content showing blurring don't why if any know Please share your feedback.

Comment: Please share a link to the site or a code sample. Replicate the issue with codepen. The modal by default is centered, so some other css or the way you have built the site is causing conflict. Impossible to know how based on screenshots.

Comment: @sean top: 50% !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
    transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
    height: auto !important;

Comment: I just used some extra code for vertical center but not working

Comment: Code pasted into the comments doesn't really count.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I use to center my modal:

```
#modal {
    top: 50% !important;
    transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(1) !important;
}
```

This should replace the `top: 10%` and `transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) !important` settings that are default in the materialize stylesheet. You can work with styling the div ID, class, or the element itself to get the style to overwrite the default materialize styles, or just replace the css in the materialize.css file itself.